# Removing columns in SQL file

Tags: sql, ruby, regex, text-processing

I have a big SQL file (~ 200MB) with lots of `INSERT` instructions:

```
insert  into `films_genres`
    (`id`,`film_id`,`genre_id`,`num`) 
    values 
    (1,1,1,1),
    (2,1,17,2),
    (3,2,1,1),
    ...
```

How could I remove or ignore columns `id`, `num` in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way might be to do the full insert into a temporary holding table and then insert the desired columns into the real table from the holding table.

```
insert  into `films_genres_temp`
    (`id`,`film_id`,`genre_id`,`num`) 
    values 
    (1,1,1,1),
    (2,1,17,2),
    (3,2,1,1),
    ...

insert into `films_genres`
    (`film_id`,`genre_id`)
    select `film_id`,`genre_id`
        from `films_genres_temp`
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl one-liner should do it:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/\([^,]+,/\(/g; s/,[^,]+\)/\)/g' sqlfile
```

It edits the file in place, but creates a backup copy with the extension .bak.

Or if you prefer Ruby:

```
ruby -p -i.bak -e 'gsub(/\([^,]+,/, "("); gsub/, ")");' sqlfile
```

Comment: +1 for the fastest and simplest method (look ma, no database).

Comment: Except the OP seems to prefer using Ruby.

Comment: Noted; added a ruby one-liner version.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (id int,film_id smallint, genre_id int, num int)

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable (`id`,`film_id`,`genre_id`,`num`)
[Data goes here]

insert into films_genres (`film_id`,`genre_id`) select `film_id`,`genre_id`         from #MyTempTable

drop table #MyTempTable